# Remove all currently applied styles for a ContentPlaceHolder in child page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, styling

I want to remove all styles that were applied by master page  for a content place holder, but do it in code within the child page.
I tried to use the following, but it did nothing.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("cphCenterColumn");
            mpContentPlaceHolder.EnableTheming = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Themes need to be changed no later than in `Page_Init` in the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).
Try moving the code to the `Page_Init` or `Page_PreInit` event instead.